Is it possible to create a cost and usage report (generated in account 1) in one S3 bucket from another AWS account (created in account 2)?
Currently I am trying to store the output of cost and usage from one account to a bucket created in a second account.
data "aws_s3_bucket" "cur" {  
bucket = "cnr-auxo-dev-cur-logs"  
provider = aws.xxxx1
}

data "aws_region" "current" {}

resource "aws_cur_report_definition" "this" {  
report_name                = "xxxxxxxx"
time_unit                  = "HOURLY"  
format                     = "Parquet"  
compression                = "Parquet"  
report_versioning          = "OVERWRITE_REPORT"  
additional_artifacts       = ["ATHENA"]  
additional_schema_elements = ["RESOURCES"]
s3_bucket = data.aws_s3_bucket.cur.bucket  
s3_region = "${data.aws_region.current.name}"  
s3_prefix = "xxxxxxx"
}

and this is the error i am having:
Error: creating Cost And Usage Report Definition (xxxxxxxx): ValidationException: 

  with aws_cur_report_definition.this,
  on cur.tf line 7, in resource "aws_cur_report_definition" "this":
   7: resource "aws_cur_report_definition" "this" {

So I doubt if aws is preventing us from managing the cost and usage report of account1 in s3 bucket of another account?
Thanks for the help !

Interesting case...  If I was to tackle this I would probably create S3 cross account replication that way we let the aws_cur_report_definition save to a local bucket and the data gets copied over by the replication process ... https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/replication-walkthrough-2.html

From looking at the documentation: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cur_report_definition#s3_bucket s3_bucket - (Required) Name of the existing S3 bucket to hold generated reports. so from just a name how will it know that bucket is on a different account? my educated guess that just does not work cross account

@helder You're right! It's not possible across accounts. I implemented it using this architecture

